# Create a report in VB.NET using ReportViewer dynamically

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know how to create a report in VB.NET using a Report Viewer programaticaly, like creating a data report?

I tried everything I've found on the internet but most of it is using the report wizard. I want something similar to creating a report in VB 6.0.

This is what I have tried so far..

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.IO

Public Class frmTestReport

    Public dsMyDataSet As New DataSet()

    Private Sub frmTestReport_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.cmbReport.Items.Add("TESTREPORT")
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnViewReport_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnViewReport.Click

        Me.ReportViewer1.Reset()

        Me.ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local

        If Me.cmbReport.Text.Trim() = "TESTREPORT" Then

            'load .rdlc file and add a datasource
            Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\Reports\MyTestReport.rdlc"
            ' ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds)

        End If

        'refresh viewer with above settings
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Edit: I want to populate my report.rdlc with a dynamic dataset , so that i can attach my desired sql queries on it but no luck, ..currently my report returns to a blank report.